# Statements on "if" not followed

Tags: c, if-statement, mplab, dspic

I´m doing a little programming on C with a dsPIC, I have found a little tiny problem that I don´t know why or how is it happenning. 
Compiler C30 for MPLAB

I have this code:

```
int Function1(){
.
.
.
while(1){
.
.
.
P1 = EPC96_1[18];  //Here the value of P1 = 0xB6
P2 = EPC96_1[19];
CRC_CCITT(EPC96_2, 18);   //in this function CRC_1 is calculated also CRC2
if(P1 != CRC_1){       //In the calculation of CRC_1 it comes always 0xB6
  P1++;                //Both values P1 and CRC1 are the same, stil it 
  if(P2 != CRC_2)      //comes here and continues with the break
    break;
  }
}
return 1;
}
//end of my function, return to main code
```

----Sorry, I didn´t specify, it supose not to come into the if, the `!=` is supose to be like that, because what I want the program to do is when both variables are equal, it should return to the `while(1)` start.----

I looked up for the variables on the Watch of the MPLAB (8.92) and they are the same. I do not think the problem is in the code before or after or in any other place, but I could be wrong.
Has anybody found the same problem during your experience time?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You say `P1` is `0xB6` and that `CRC_1` also is `0xB6`.  In that case `P1 == CRC_1` and the `if`-statement will not be followed (it has `!=`).

Comment: How is `CRC_1` set by the `CRC_CCITT()` function? Did you mean `CRC_1 = CRC_CCITT(EPC96_2, 18)`? Or is it a global variable?

Comment: In my experience, strange issues like these are due to my own bugs.  I will never question the compiler unless two different compilers show different behaviour (which is *very* rare).

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `P1` and `CRC_1` are `int` variables.

According to the comments in your code, both variables will have value `0xB6`.  The `if`-statement checks for inequality (`!=`), not equality (`==`), so it will skip the block.

I suggest inserting `printf()`-statements to output the values of the two variables before and/or inside the `if`-statement.  It may be that either one of them holds unexpected values.

```
printf("P1=%d, CRC_1=%d\n", P1, CRC_1);
```

Comment: `printf()` won't help him much on an embedded platform.

Comment: @TimČas Well, step through with a debugger then. If that's what he's doing with *Watch*, then he's most likely either misreading the screen (0xB6 is really 0x86, for example), or he's not running the program he think he is.

Answer (score 0):

The data type of variables are unknown.
What datatype of P1, P2, EPC96_1, CRC_1, CRC_2?
Where the variable are defined?
What function CR_CCCITT() is do?